# Using gdb to convert addresses to lines

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I have a stack trace generated by a stripped application which looks like this:

```
 *** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f0e442d392d  (unknown)
    @     0x7f0e442d7b1f  (unknown)
    @     0x7f0e442d7067  (unknown)
    @     0x7f0e442d801d  (unknown)
    @     0x7f0e457c55e6  (unknown)
    @     0x7f0e457c5696  (unknown)
    @           0x4e8765  (unknown)
    @           0x4a8b43  (unknown)
    @     0x7f0e43197ced  (unknown)
    @           0x4a6889  (unknown)
```

And I have a non-stripped version of the executable and all of its libraries ( compiled with debug information). But how can I translate the address into files and line numbers??

Here is what I have tried:

```
gdb
set solib-absolute-prefix /path/to/non-stripped/edition/of/root/filesystem/sysroot/
file /path/to/non-stripped/edition/of/root/filesystem/sysroot/usr/bin/my-buggy-app
info line *0x7f0e457c5696
```

When I type in the file command it only loads symbols from the file, not all the libraries which are used. Is there a way this can be done?

The "info line" command says:

> No line number information available for address 0x7f0e442d801d

Which I assumes is because the address is in one of the shared libraries, but how can I know in which one of them?

Comment: [`addr2line`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/addr2line1.html) ?

Comment: @another.anon.coward Year, I tried that but I do not know how which file to look in, as the addresses is pointing to shared libraries.

Comment: @Allan: you can use `info sharedlibrary` command to know which shared library the addresses `0x7f0e442d801d` belongs to.

Comment: Not tried this, but `add-symbol-file filename address` could possibly help to load symbols from shared libraries (one at a time). http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_125.html

Comment: Found a library without symbols in `sharedlibrary` and `list 0xaddress` did not show any source. I ran `add-symbol-file file addr` and then `list 0xaddress` showed source code.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> But how can I translate the address into files and line numbers?

For the main executable (addresses like `0x4e8765`) do this:

```
addr2line -e /path/to/non-stripped/.../my-buggy-app \
    0x4a6889 0x4a8b43 0x4e8765
```

Actually, you might want to subtract `5` (usual length of the `CALL` instruction) from all of the above addresses.

For the addresses in shared libraries, you have to know the load address of the library.

If your application produced a `core` file, then `(gdb) info shared` will tell you where libraries were loaded.

If you did not get a core file, and the application did not print the required mapping, then

- you should fix the application so it does print that info (the stack trace is mostly useless without it), and
- you could still guess: look at the code in the executable at `0x4e8760` -- it should be a `CALL` instruction to some function. Now find out which library that function is in, and find its address in the library (via `nm`). If you are lucky, that address is near `0xNc56NN`. You can now guess the load address of whatever library is at `0x7f0e457NNNNNN`. Repeat for `0x7f0e457c55e1`, and you can find out the load address of library at `0x7f0e442dNNNN`.

Comment: I came here because `addr2line` does not always work, while GDB is rock solid.

Answer (score 56):

Per the OP, the command in GDB to find the source line of code from an address is:

```
info line *0x10045740
```

**Edit**:  Replaced "info symbol 0x10045740" which won't work under certain conditions (thanks @Thomasa88).

Comment: This only displays the symbol + offset (`LftPlugin::import_clicked() const + 1522 in section .text of /home/thomas/.kde4/lib64/kde4/kmm_lft.so`), while `info line *0xabc` shows the line number (`Line 97 of "plugin/lft_plugin.cpp" starts at address 0x7fffe49eb39c <LftPlugin::import_clicked() const+1522> and ends at 0x7fffe49eb3ad <LftPlugin::import_clicked() const+1539>.`). In my case my shared library is not stripped though, but `add-symbol-file filename address` could possibly help when the symbols are stripped. http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_125.html

Comment: how to do this in mi mode?